# Extract all matches unless string contains

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I am using the **re** package's `re.findall` to extract terms from strings.  How can I make a regex to say capture these matches unless you see this substring (in this case the substring `"fake"`).  I attempted this via a anchored look-ahead solution.

**Current Output:**

```
import re

for x in ['a man dogs', "fake: too many dogs", 'hi']:
    print(re.findall(r"(man[a-z]?\b|dog)(?!^.*fake)", x, flags=re.IGNORECASE))


## ['man', 'dog']
## ['many', 'dog']
## []
```

**Desired Output**

```
## ['man', 'dog']
## []
## []
```

I could accomplish this with an if/else but was wondering how to use a pure regex to solve this?

```
for x in ['a man dogs', "fake: too many dogs", 'hi']:
    if re.search('fake', x, flags=re.IGNORECASE):
        print([])
    else:
        print(re.findall(r"(man[a-z]?\b|dog)", x, flags=re.IGNORECASE))

## ['man', 'dog']
## []
## []
```

Comment: A regex is not the most efficient way to do this.  `if "fake" not in x:` is probably better.

Comment: Only with PyPi `regex`: `r"(?<!fake.*)(man[a-z]?\b|dog)(?!.*fake)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `re` does not support unknown length lookbehind patterns, the plain regex solution is not possible. However, the PyPi regex library supports such lookbehind patterns.

After installing PyPi regex, you can use

```py
(?<!fake.*)(man[a-z]?\b|dog)(?!.*fake)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CqN9OU/1).

*Details*:

- `(?<!fake.*)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is `fake` string followed with any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible immediately to the left of the current location
- `(man[a-z]?\b|dog)` - `man` + a lowercase ASCII letter followed with a word boundary or `dog` string
- `(?!.*fake)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then a `fake` string immediately to the left of the current location.

In Python:

```py
import regex
for x in ['a man dogs', "fake: too many dogs", 'hi']:
    print(regex.findall(r"(?<!fake.*)(man[a-z]?\b|dog)(?!.*fake)", x, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your pattern `(man[a-z]?\b|dog)(?!^.*fake)` the negative lookahead is after the match, but the word fake can still occur before one of the matches.

With Python `re` you can get out of the way what you don't want to keep, and capture what you want to keep using a capture group.

What you could do is not use a negative lookahead, but match a whole line that contains the word `fake`

```
^.*\bfake\b.*|(man[a-z]?\b|dog)
```

**Explanation**

- `^.*\bfake\b.*` Match a whole line that contains the word `fake`
- `|` Or
- `(man[a-z]?\b|dog)` Capture **group 1**, match either `man` and optional char a-z or match `dog`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ymm7ai/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/EdXNai)

```
import re

pattern = r"^.*\bfake\b.*|(man[a-z]?\b|dog)"

for x in ['a man dogs', "fake: too many dogs", 'hi']:
    res = [s for s in re.findall(pattern, x, re.IGNORECASE) if s]
    print(res)
```

Output

```
['man', 'dog']
[]
[]
```